# javascript change object variable reference

Tags: javascript, object, reference

I'm new to javascript could someone please explain why this code doesn't work?

```
var User = function () {
    var userId = 0;
    var clear = function () {
        userId = 0;
    }
    return{
        clear:clear,
        userId:userId,
    }
}

...
// in mocha test:

var john = new User();
john.userId = 666;
john.userId.should.equal(666); // true
john.clear()
john.userId.should.equal(0); // false
```

Regards

Comment: You create a `User` object and assign the object reference to the variable `john`.  Then you proceed to reference an undeclared variable called `user`.

Comment: `user.id` and `id` within the constructor are two different things. One is what other languages call `public`, while the other one is `private`. They may share the name, but point towards different memory locations.

Comment: Sorry, got a typo. Updated the question.

Comment: I created a fiddle for you.

https://jsfiddle.net/tqc1wrkp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done is create a [function closure](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp). This means that inside the `clear` function, `userId` is created as a local variable and is separately scoped from the global `User.userId`.

What you need to do is use the `this` keyword to specify the `userId` you are trying to change is the global one.

```
var User = function () {
    var userId = 0;
    var clear = function () {
        this.userId = 0;
    }
    return{
        clear:clear,
        userId:userId,
    }
}
```

Comment: although the `var userId = 0;` is redundant then.

Comment: @Sirko without that the code will error (at least in my runtime)! See error in the console: https://jsfiddle.net/r7mp7e6r/

Comment: Sure it will as there is the reference in the returned object. You would have to set the zero there directly.

Comment: Ahh I misunderstood - you were saying the initialization in that place was pointless.

Comment: Having two pointers to the same value is pointless in this example, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an object

```
 return{
    clear:clear,
    userId:userId,
}
```

which doesn't have an id property, but userId.

Comment: var john = new User(), and then u reference user? try john.clear()

Comment: try removing the var before defining the User 'class'.
Just do User = function() {}

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the this keyword.

```
var User = function () {
    var userId = 0;
    var clear = function () {
        this.userId = 0;
    }
    return{
        clear:clear,
        userId:userId,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "this" when referencing the property in the clear method

```
var clear = function () {
    this.userId = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here.

1 : `userId` is undefined in your function definition.

2: `user` is undefined, so `user.clear()` is also undefined (actually, I'm surprised your code doen't just crash). You mean `john.id` and  `john.clear()`.

Comment: I think these were both typos - the asker edited his question to reflect this.

Comment: Indeed, while I was typing my answer. OP asks why their code doesn't work, but posts something full of typos.........